# Why does Phineas and Ferb's dad never react when his sons making inventions in front of his eyes?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, phineas-and-ferb

If you watched Phineas & Ferb from start to finish, you might have noticed that sometimes they outright tell their dad about their inventions or sometimes he can see it with his own eyes.

It's save to assume that if their mom saw what the boys were doing, she would punish them. Because why would Candace be trying to bust her brothers by telling her mom instead of dad? Candace knows that dad wouldn't react.

So, the question is, why does Phineas and Ferb's  dad never react as you would think he should when he learns what his boys were doing? Why does he just go with it?

Answer (score 2):

He is following the stereotype that mothers are generally more concerned about safety and fathers are more frequently absent-minded and willing to participate in their child's shenanigans. Molly and Arthur Weasley follow a similar pattern - when Fred, George, and Ron steal their father's flying car, Mrs. Weasley gives them the lecture of a lifetime, whereas Mr. Weasley is initially excited that they managed to pull it off and only pretends disapproval when prompted by his wife.

Comment: Because dads generally don't care what their children do. So, whenever Phineas and Ferb's dad sees their sons doing something out-of-ordinary, he just doesn't put too much thought into it even if in his own mind, he might think that something is not exactly right with his sons. And at the end of the day, it doesn't matter, because Linda is boss in the family.